# How can I prove that $_{max}|Az^{n}+b|$ =$ |A|$ + $|B|$ when |Z| $\leq$ 1?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, soft-question

How can I prove that $_{max}$$|Az^{n}+B|$ = $|A| + |B|$ when $|Z|$ $\leq$ 1?

Remember that Z is a complex number which is why I had to include the magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

first, if $|z|\leq1$, then $|Az^{n}+B|\leq |A|+|B|$

Let $A=r_1e^{i\alpha}, B=r_2e^{i\beta}$. Take

$$z=e^{i\frac{\beta-\alpha}n}$$

then $Az^{n}+B=r_1e^{i\beta}+r_2e^{i\beta}$, so $|Az^{n}+B|=r_1+r_2=|A|+|B|$

Comment: I might be a noob, but can you explain the reasoning why taking $z=e^{\dfrac{\beta -\alpha}{n}}

Comment: argument of $Az^{n}, B$ are the same, so $Az^{n}, B$  colinear, $|Az^{n}+B|=|A|+|B|$

Comment: How can you ensure that z=e^{\dfrac{\beta -\alpha}{n}} is less than 1?

Comment: $|e^{i\frac{\beta-\alpha}n}|=1$

Comment: How do you derive that conclusion? Sorry it's been a while since I learned this stuff for the first time

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula

Comment: Oh yeah, LOL. My bad! You are really smart

Comment: How do you know that the argument of az^n and b are the same?

Comment: Hey how do you know that the argument of az^n and b are the same????? @ziang chen